# Form validation passing correct error message when using react-hook register

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using react-hook `useFormContext`, we can register form validation via

```
const { register, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext();

return ( 
  ...
  <TextField
    {...register('error msg that gets sent to FieldErrors', { required: true })}
    name="m1"
    fullWidth
    error={errors['error msg that gets sent to FieldErrors']?.type === 'required'}
  />
)
```

So here the `register` sets the `name` of my `TextField` form field to `error msg that gets sent to FieldErrors` which I don't want instead I want `m1` to be the name of my `TextField` and I want the register to send `error message that gets sent to FieldErrors` as the message to my `FieldErrors`. The way I have it above does set my `TextField` name to `m1` since I explicitly used the `name` attribute in my `TextField` form however it is producing weird behavior when I try to access the error via `FieldErrors` like below

```
const showQuestionnaireErrors = (errors: FieldErrors) => {
    {Object.entries(errors).map(([fieldId, errorProps]) => (
        // some code 
    )
}
```

So my question is if there is a way where `register('some error message', { required: true })` does not set the name attribute of my form? I want my `FieldErrors` to get the correct error message instead of passing the name in register.

Comment: What you are asking fundamentally doesn't make sense. Why would you want `m1` to be the `name` for the input field, when `register` is conveniently doing that for you? What you are doing here is essentially having 2 `name` properties in the same input element when translated from what `register` has done for you. If you want `FieldErrors` to get the correct error message, you should hold all of the error messages into one big `errorMessage` object with a pair of keys and messages.

Comment: @TaiweiTuan Can you please elaborate on how I can pass the correct error message to `FieldErrors`?

Comment: You will define different kinds of error messages in `register`, such as `required`, `minLength`, `pattern`, or even custom validator. Then you parse the error from the `formState`. Please take a look at this CodeSandbox created by official useHookForm author https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-errormessage-multiple-error-messages-3ur2z

Comment: you can use  yup for form validation with schema it's easy to use @user21476047